# launch cocos2dx project with Android

Tags: android, ant, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm using Cocos2dx 3.0 RC1, and in the installation i typed : `./setup.py`

I entered my NDK root, and my SDK root, but didn't put anything on my ANT root as explained in this tutorial : [here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_run_cpp-tests_on_Android)
. But know when i use : `cocos run -s ~/MyCompany/MyGame -p android`, it says that my ANT_ROOT is not defined. I've installed it using Macport, but when i type ant, it says Build is missing.

I just want to create a game in Android using Cocos2dx.

Answer (score 3):

You could go ahead and define ANT_ROOT in your `.bash_profile`.

```
export ANT_ROOT=<where ever it is>
export PATH=$ANT_ROOT:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as OP. My .bash_profile already contained the exports; however it seems that it wasn't loaded. So just

`source ~/.bash_profile`

did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

For macOS:

Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). Run `brew install ant`. Add the export (with correct location) to your `.bash_profile` file:

`export ANT_ROOT=/usr/local/bin`